# Using #dom_id(obj) within controller to set variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use the method `dom_id(arg)` within my controller.  It has always worked in my views:

```
# in controller
@blog = Blog.first

# then in view
<%= dom_id(@blog)%>
  => "blog_1"
```

However: *setting* a variable via `dom_id` does not work when doing it in the controller:

```
# ALL in controller
@blog = Blog.first
@dom_id_var = dom_id(@blog)
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `dom_id' for main:Object
```

Is it possible to use `dom_id` within the controller?

[Docs on dom_id](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/RecordIdentifier/dom_id)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Inside your conroller, Try to add

```
class YourController    
include ActionView::RecordIdentifier
...

end
```

Answer (score 17):

Call `helpers.dom_id(@blog)` in your controller action:

```rb
class SomeController < ApplicationController

  def some_action
    ...
    @dom_id = helpers.dom_id(@blog)
    ...
  end
```

Rails 5 and above provides the `#helpers` method to allow you to call view helper methods within controllers.